Writing to a json file in Julia
I am new to Julia, and trying to write to a tokens.json file. However, I keep getting various errors.
Consider a Dict() data,
open("tokens.json", "w") do f
    JSON.print(f, data)
end

I keep getting the error:
SystemError: opening file "tokens.json": Invalid argument

Stacktrace:
 [1] systemerror(p::String, errno::Int32; extrainfo::Nothing)
   @ Base .\error.jl:176
 [2] systemerror
   @ .\error.jl:175 [inlined]
 [3] open(fname::String; lock::Bool, read::Nothing, write::Nothing, create::Nothing, truncate::Bool, append::Nothing)
   @ Base .\iostream.jl:293
 [4] open
   @ .\iostream.jl:275 [inlined]
 [5] open(fname::String, mode::String; lock::Bool)
   @ Base .\iostream.jl:356
 [6] open(fname::String, mode::String)
   @ Base .\iostream.jl:355
 [7] open(::var"#17#18", ::String, ::Vararg{String}; kwargs::@Kwargs{})
   @ Base .\io.jl:394
 [8] open(::Function, ::String, ::String)
   @ Base .\io.jl:393
 [9] top-level scope
   @ In[47]:1

I've tried use_mmap=false and every other fix I've seen online.

Does your data looks simple, like this? data = Dict("k1" => "v1", "k2" => "v2")

Can you include the version of Julia you are using and some sample code that fails when the use_mmap=false kwarg is passed? I cannot reproduce this on my computer with the supplied example.

Yes, it is a simple dictionary{String, Any} with only six entries.
I get the same error when using use_mmap=false. When I write the file, it works initially. Then if I go back and change the variable, it no longer lets me write to the file.

The following code should create a dictionary, write to a JSON file, load the file that was written, and print the JSON to standard output.
Note: The following code was ran with Julia 1.10.3
Setup
Import the JSON and Logging, along with defining a read/write function.
using JSON
using Logging

const JSON_FILE = "tokens.json"

function read_json(file::String)::Dict
    open(file, "r") do f
        return JSON.parse(f)
    end
end

function write_json(file::String, data::Dict)
    open(file, "w") do f
        JSON.print(f, data)
    end
end

Execution
Define the data, write/read from JSON file, and print as neccessary.
# Define dictionary
data = Dict("k1" => "v1", "k2" => "v2")

# Write the dictionary to a JSON file
try
    write_json(JSON_FILE, data)
    println("Successfully wrote JSON to ", JSON_FILE)
    
    # Read the dictionary from the JSON file
    loaded = read_json(JSON_FILE)
    
    # Print the loaded dictionary
    println("Loaded dictionary: ", loaded)
    
    # Print the formatted JSON to the standard output with a prefix
    println("Formatted JSON:")
    JSON.print(stdout, loaded, 2)
catch e
    @warn "Failed to write or read JSON: $e"
end

